# Make Chrome always execute with flags, for eg., directly opening an HTML file

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-registry

I want to run Chrome with a given set of flags, **always**

I created a shortcut and added the flag to it in the following way, so my target of the shortcut says:

```
C:\<application-path>\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=D:\Chrome
```

But when I double click an HTML file, or if **any other application** triggers Chrome, it looses the flag value. The result - A new chrome window opens with Default profile directory.

I want to make the flag permanent, so that its active irrespective of however Chrome executes.

I tried changing the following **registry key**:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command
```

It was this earlier:

```
"C:\<application-path>\chrome.exe" -- "%1"
```

I changed to following attempts which **did not work**:

```
1. "C:\<application-path>\chrome.exe" -- "%1" --user-data-dir=D:\Chrome
2. "C:\<application-path>\chrome.exe" -- "%1" -- "user-data-dir=D:\Chrome"
3. "C:\<application-path>\chrome.exe" -- "%1 user-data-dir=D:\Chrome"
```

Conclusively, when I try to open a link from any application, it doesn't open in my current Chrome as a new tab, rather opens a new Chrome window with no plugins and extensions since its from other directory.

Why I have changed my default directory? - because the OS drive was getting low on memory due to heave Chrome caches and apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--` as a program option means "all arguments that follow aren't program options, but files to open". `--user-data-dir=D:\Chrome` is an option, but Chrome reads `--` first and treats that option as a filename.

Try changing that registry value to the following:

```
"C:\<application-path>\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir=D:\Chrome -- "%1"
```

There's also another option. If you don't need the default profile at all and want to replace it with `D:\Chrome` permanently, then you can replace that profile's directory with a symlink to `D:\Chrome`. Chrome will still try to load the default profile, but filesystem will redirect it to your custom profile.

Comment: Forgot to comment that the later part of your answer works like a charm, which is what I initially wanted.
Looks like `symlinking` directories is the only way to save space consumed by Chrome.