# How can I disable accelerated compositing in Chrome without relying on a shortcut or .bat?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, command-line-arguments

I'm using BBLean as an Explorer replacement to save myself a little screen space (among other things), but it's a bit finicky with Google Chrome, breaking page rendering in most situations. After some Googling and experimentation, I found that using the --blacklist-accelerated-compositing flag fixed my issues while Explorer wasn't running. I added it to the shortcut I use to launch Chrome, and everything was peachy.

The problem is that Chrome is also my URL handler everywhere, and when it launches from clicking a link in Skype or IRC, it launches without the flag that I need set for it to render anything.  Poking around in chrome://flags reveals a lot of options that look related, but don't seem to work.

I need some way to ensure that Chrome has this flag properly set even when launched as a URL handler. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: [Make Chrome always execute with flags](http://superuser.com/q/600147)

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `chrome://flags/` in Chrome and try to set **GPU compositing on all pages** to **disabled** and **enable "Disable accelerated 2D canvas"**.

Or perhaps you can try [adding `chrome.exe` to BBLean's exclusion list](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=13766#c5).

If related, you may also follow [Chromiun issue #172590](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=172590).

Comment: Tried those: weirdly enough, no success. The BBLean exclusion list has to do with the BBLeanSkin plugin, which works with title bars and naturally misbehaves with Chrome's tab bar (so naturally I've had it disabled for a while), but after setting both suggested options, most pages still break.

Comment: Seems like `GPU compositing on all pages` was removed sometime in the last 10 years.