# How to run Chrome always with specific commands

Tags: windows, command-line, google-chrome

I want to configure some PCs on my network, to always run Chrome, with some specific commands like:

> --app-shell-host-window-size, --window-size...

and some others...

I can do this changing the shortcut (lnk) of Desktop, inserting the command line on Path, but I think this is too 'high level', and can be easily changeable (accidentally or intentionally). Is there any other way to configure Chrome to always run with some command line?

I accept suggestions outside Chrome software, for example, Windows registry.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making a simple program that has a config file where you can specify the programs it launches and with which params you want, that is actually easy to make, well i don't know if you're a programmer, but still. And then make the icon of the program the same as Chrome, and make a shortcut of it in desktop with the name Google Chrome, that will work, unless an update breaks it, which by then you can edit the config files with the new directory. So that when someone click "Google Chrome" in desktop it will launch the program that will then launch chrome with specified params then exit.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that... It's an idea, thank you... Still preferring native solutions...

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/600147/make-chrome-always-execute-with-flags-for-eg-directly-opening-an-html-file?rq=1

Comment: Or you can just add the flags to the chrome executable, it worked for me in games, so i think it will work on executables generally

Comment: Yes, that related post is good, but isn't working as I expected. If I remove the parameters `--chrome-frame --window-size=800,600` from shortcut and leave on registry `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --chrome-frame --window-size=800,600 -- "%1"` , doesn't work...